# Unable to open the avd which is created

Tags: java, android

i created a avd named droidX which later wen i am starting that avd it could not open it just hangs showing "Starting emulator for droidX"

Answer (score 0):

you can use bluestack emulator  http://www.bluestacks.com/

1) open bluestacks emulator.

2) go to your  environment variable settings and click on path variable and add the path of your abd in the **platform-tools**  folder (Optional if you have done it before.)

3)open **cmd** and type adb connect **adb connect 127.0.0.1**

4)now open eclipse and click on project -> run as-> Android Aplication and you should see blueStack emulator running.